# A conceptual and condractictory question about Gauss law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]Suppose we have a charge q which is placed at some distance from the center inside a conducting spherical shell of equal and opposite charge. Now according to gauss law the charge of the outer shell would be distributed in the inner surface non uniformly such that all the field lines passing throught it become perpendicular to the surface and that the shell becomes equipotential. Now heres where I am confused, suppose we get a charge from infinity and keep it on the surface of the shell, I am getting contradicted now according to gauss law there cannot be any electric field outside the shell as there are two equal and opposite charges and if we take a gaussian surface we get the same result.Therefore no work should be required to keep it on the surface, but if the surface is an equipotential surely its potential cannot be zero, therfore some work must be required. Could anyone clarify this for me, also i took the equal and opposite charges just for simplicity.

Comment: Did you remember to calculate the work required to bring the charge in from infinity to the surface of the sphere?

Comment: Zero flux through the surface outside does not mean the field is identically zero there.

Comment: @ConnorBehan yes I am aware of that but I have learnt that any charge inside a conducting surface does not produce any effect outside it.

Comment: Right, but the charge brought from infinity affects the outside. A gaussian surface around the equal and opposite charges will only imply that whatever field is there has zero flux.